# Slow SUM for 77k rows table with 1 big column

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, database-design

Consider following Table Structure ( 77k rows and 237MB dump size, column cart_data_json as of right now can be as big as 0.01k to 50k characters )

```
CREATE TABLE `commerce_sales_test` (
  `commerce_sales_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `commerce_sales_date` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `total` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  **`cart_data_json` mediumtext,**
  PRIMARY KEY (`commerce_sales_id`),
  KEY `fast_sdate` (`commerce_sales_date` DESC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

Running COUNT(*) is really fast.
Running SUM(total) would perform really2 slow ( 1-5 seconds slow , depending on the WHERE Statement ).
Running Select statement with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS also really slow ( regardless the limit ).

The following queries run in sub 30ms  regardless of the WHERE statement ( i can remove the where completely and the queries still run very fast )

```
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM  commerce_sales_test AS cs
        WHERE  cs.commerce_sales_date >= 1673222400
          AND  cs.commerce_sales_date <= 1699844800 ;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    35884 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.026 sec)
```

```
    SELECT  cs.commerce_sales_id, cs.cart_data_json, cs.total
        FROM  commerce_sales_test AS cs
        WHERE  cs.commerce_sales_date >= 1673222400
          AND  cs.commerce_sales_date <= 1699844800
        LIMIT  0 , 15;

15 rows in set (0.003 sec)
```

The following queries run in 1-5 seconds , depending on the row found by where statement

```
    SELECT  COUNT(*), sum(cs.total)
        FROM  commerce_sales_test AS cs
        WHERE  cs.commerce_sales_date >= 1673222400
          AND  cs.commerce_sales_date <= 1699844800 ;
+----------+---------------+
| COUNT(*) | sum(cs.total) |
+----------+---------------+
|    35884 |    2631697732 |
+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (1.010 sec)
```

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS cs.commerce_sales_id, cs.cart_data_json, cs.total FROM commerce_sales_test AS cs
WHERE  cs.commerce_sales_date >= 1673222400  AND cs.commerce_sales_date <= 1699844800   
LIMIT 0 , 15;

15 rows in set (1.879 sec)
```

I did try changing the cart_data_json into varchar(64000) , but the same problem still presists ( and for my case I might need more than 65k text )

```
    SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS cs.commerce_sales_id, cs.total
        FROM  commerce_sales_test AS cs
        WHERE  cs.commerce_sales_date >= 1673222400
          AND  cs.commerce_sales_date <= 1799844800
        LIMIT  0 , 15;
+--------------------------+---------+
| commerce_sales_id        | total   |
+--------------------------+---------+
| 240109141243/5T47/4S5    |  183000 |
| 240107212543/5T28/9S386  |  224800 |
| 240107212533/5T29/13S384 |   52900 |
| 240107212405/5T29/13S384 | 1288000 |
| 240107212225/5T29/13S384 |   31300 |
| 240107212130/5T29/13S384 |  122500 |
| 240107212107/5T16/11S382 |   10700 |
| 240107211912/5T29/13S384 |  238700 |
| 240107211817/5T28/9S386  |   27000 |
| 240107211805/5T32/12S383 |   39700 |
| 240107211522/5T32/12S383 |   18900 |
| 240107211354/5T32/12S383 |   34300 |
| 240107211342/5T29/13S384 |  100100 |
| 240107211121/5T29/13S384 |  107300 |
| 240107210954/5T28/9S386  |    5000 |
+--------------------------+---------+
15 rows in set, 1 warning (1.556 sec)
```

I did try to put only 100 characters max on the cart_data_json MEDIUMTEXT column, this increases all queries tremendously.

**Currently what I really need is to able to perform SUM fast, what should I do?**
For SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, I can simply run separate count(*) queries to retrieve total row count.

I am guessing that the solution might be to increase some memory settings?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you can try `alter table commerce_sales_test drop key fast_sdate, add key fast_sdate (commerce_sales_date DESC, total)` so it gets the totals while reading the index rather than having to read the table rows.

Comment: If you store json data in a column, then why don't you use json column type?

Answer (score 2):

Here's several lessons on InnoDB INDEXing:

- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` uses the smallest `INDEX` (the one on date).  So there is very little to fetch from disk (or find cached in the buffer_pool).
- Adding a range test on date made it faster because it did not need to scan the entire index.
- `SELECT ... big_column ...` needs to do an extra disk fetch for the big (json in `MEDIUMTEXT`, in your case.  This adds lots to the time.
- Changing to `VARCHAR(64000)` had no impact because the "off record" storage for large columns still applied.
- `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` stops delivering rows according to `LIMIT`, but then proceeds to fetch (and toss) the rest of the rows.
- `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` should not be used anymore -- MySQL 8 has removed it from the language.  So, your two-query alternative was good.  Furthermore (see above), doing simply `COUNT(*)` instead of listing columns (including the json) is much faster.
- Without `LIMIT` and without `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` there were at most 15 off-record lookups.
- The grand total (`sum(cs.total)` without `LIMIT`) took an intermediate amount of time because it had to bounce between the `INDEX` BTree and the data BTree 77K times.  This can be sped up considerably by providing a "covering" `INDEX(commerce_sales_date, total)` *instead* of the current index on just the date.  "Covering" eliminates the "bounce back and forth".
- "100 characters max" eliminates the "off-record" lookups.
- "Off-record" storage comes into play whenever a give row takes more than about 8KB.
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of available RAM.  If it is currently less than, say, 500M, then you *might* benefit from increasing the setting (and increasing RAM if necessary).  (The 500M is a crude estimate based on your 237MB.)